# My API url works in the Chrome browser, but it won't work in my test apache local host environment

Tags: javascript, apache, api, xampp, openweathermap

When I put this into the browser, it brings back the json object just fine to me with all the weather data:
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=90210&units=imperial&appid={API Key}

However, I'm using my XAMPP Apache in the htdocs folder to try and test it out in my code. Can someone please look at my code and see what in the what is wrong here? Thank you so much for the help.

```js
var weatherInfo = document.getElementById("weather");
var zipCodeForm = document.getElementById("zipCodeForm");

function getWeather(zipCode){
 //create the url for the request
 var endpoint = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather";
 var apiKey = {API Key};
 var queryString = "zip=" + zipCode + "&units=imperial&appid=" + apiKey;
 var url = endpoint + "?" +queryString;

 //create the request to get the weather data
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.addEventListener("load", responseReceivedHandler);
 xhr.requestType = "json";
 xhr.open("GET", url);
 xhr.send();

 console.log("getWeather")
 console.log(xhr.response.status);
}

function responseReceivedHandler(){
 if(this.status === 200){
  weatherInfo.innerHTML = "Current temperature: " + this.response.main.temp;
 }

 else{
  weatherInfo.innerHTML="Not working";
 }

 console.log("responseReceivedHandler")


}

getWeather(90210);
```

```html
 <body>
  <form id="zipCodeForm">
   <label for="zipCode">Please enter your zip code: </label>
   <input type="text" name="zipCode" id="zipCode">
   <input type="submit" name="submit">
  </form>

  <div id="weather"></div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Without your API key it's going to be difficult for us to test it. (Please do *not* share your API key!) Also, "it won't work" is kind of vague. Are you seeing any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: {"coord":{"lon":-118.41,"lat":34.09},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":81.19,"feels_like":80.19,"temp_min":75.2,"temp_max":86,"pressure":1013,"humidity":44},"visibility":16093,"wind":{"speed":5.82,"deg":220},"clouds":{"all":1},"dt":1588786879,"sys":{"type":1,"id":5872,"country":"US","sunrise":1588769932,"sunset":1588819291},"timezone":-25200,"id":0,"name":"Beverly Hills","cod":200}......................The browser link gives me all the correct data. But when I test it by running my code, I get a 401 error

Comment: When I delete the "?" in my url variable, i get the 401 error. When I add it back in, I get undefined. I feel like the "?" should be there though

Comment: What is "the browser link"? And where are you seeing/detecting this 401 error? 401 is the HTTP code for [unauthorized](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) which means you're probably failing to specify the correct API key.

Comment: The "?" is part of the URL. Why would you remove it?

Comment: It's not the wrong API. When I copy and paste that API link into a browser like chrome, it returns the json object.... When I use that same API information in my code as pasted above and run it on my apache localhost, I get the 401 error or undefined when I console.log(xhr.response.status)

Comment: I wouldn't remove the ?, I mean I'm just trying everything in the world to get it to work. I agree it should be there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213266/discussion-between-kmoser-and-amber).

Answer (score 0):

HERE IS THE SOLUTION!!

My response needed to be converted from json to javascript object. It kept giving me undefined when I tried this.response.main.temp. The way I figured it out was the when I tried this.response[0], the result was a “{”. I was like, okay, so this must be unable to interpret this json as an object. It’s just a string of all the json characters. So I found json.parse() in order to turn it into a javascript object, and bam-- API ping success with the ability to access all the data.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could just change "requestType = "json"" to responseType = json.... instead of having to parse it into an object. It's not requestType. It's responseType.